# Excel stacked line chart shows transition to 0 when empty cell but I don't want it to

Tags: excel, charts

[image]
I have 2 sets of actual data that need to be stacked. At the current month I want to show 2 sets of projected data also stacked but the transition is currently gradual as if the empty cells are treated as zeroes. I want a vertical separation between the actual and projected.

I'm using Excel (2013). I've tried: 
- The Hidden and Empty cells setting... but it locked on Zero (other options greyed out)
- Using #N/A
- Changing ranges (this works when the gap is at the end but not for the Projected values.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was down-voted. Perhaps it's seen as not coding related. To provide some context, this is part of a project in which I use SQL data to  update data series in a Powerpoint document to update KPI graphs each month. A solution that involves VBA is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate the data with the zero into two series ie either side of the zero , then plot the two series ie left part and right part.

Another way would be to have a second chart, transarent except for the second part of the data series sitting on top...

Used to do that with forecasting based on previous values, what looked like one line actually had two charts overlaid one on the other.

So, based on the comment built this:

[image]

So, you can now follow and complete the detail you need.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions @Solar Mike but I haven't been able to implement them yet. 1) I thought I had separated the two series  (see above) and 2) When I plot the projected values on their own (they still have the leading rise from 0)